# Turn off controller from moving mouse

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, mouse

so I have a Kabalo Gaming Vibration Racing Steering Wheel for racing. 
It works great but I have one problem. It's able to move the mouse and by extension, centres it to the centre of my screen. How would I disable it so it can not move my mouse? Using Kubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the answer of Jonathan does not work anymore. (ubuntu 18.04)

replace "False" with "off" (small characters !!)

add or change 
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-joystick.conf 
to this content:

```
Section "InputClass"
  Identifier "joystick catchall"
  MatchIsJoystick "on"
  MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
  Driver "joystick"
  Option "StartKeysEnabled" "off" # Disable mouse support of joypad 
  Option "StartMouseEnabled" "off"
EndSection
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for 20.04 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out how. Create and edit a new textfile at `/user/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-joystick.conf` with the following content:

```
Section "InputClass"
  Identifier "joystick catchall"
  MatchIsJoystick "on"
  MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
  Driver "joystick"
  Option “StartKeysEnabled” “False” #Disable mouse
  Option “StartMouseEnabled” “False” #support
EndSection
```

Comment: solved my issue with Steam and my Wii U Pro controller ! thanks